# While testing yolov3 model getting cuda error >> CUDA status Error: file: ./src/dark_cuda.c : ()

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, yolo, darknet

```
CUDA status Error: file: ./src/dark_cuda.c : () : line: 39 : build time: Feb  9 2021 - 13:15:44 

CUDA Error: no CUDA-capable device is detected
CUDA Error: no CUDA-capable device is detected: Bad file descriptor
darknet: ./src/utils.c:331: error: Assertion `0' failed.
```

I trained a yolov3 model on custom data on G-Colab, got this error while testing.
**In yolov3 cfg for testing am taking batch = 1 and subdivisons = 1
while for training I took batch = 32 and subdivisions = 8**

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running this
darknet >> https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

```
%cd darknet
!sed -i 's/GPU=0/GPU=1/g' Makefile
!cat Makefile
!make
```